# Solving a series of system equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

Let $P = <p_1, \ldots,p_k>$,
    $Q = <q_1, \ldots,q_k>$
    and PQ = v
Solve for P and Q, where

1. $p_1q_1 + p_2q_2 + \ldots + p_kq_k = v$
2. $q_1 + q_2 + \ldots + q_k = t$
3. $P$ is an AP series with $a_1, a_1+d, \ldots, a_1+(k-1)d$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You have $k+2$ unknowns ($a$ and $d$ to determine $P$ and $q_1...q_k$ for $Q$) and only two equations. So you have $k$ degrees of freedom.

So you could for example make the following $k$ choices: $q_3=...=q_k=0$, and some values for $a$ and $d$ (non-zero). This leaves you with the following system of two equations with two unknowns:

$$q_1+q_2=t\\aq_1+(a+d)q_2 = v$$

Solve these for $q_1$ and $q_2$ and you have one of the infinitely many possible answers.